image_tag not returning image using url in service
module FileService
  class LetterGenerator
    def initialize(user)
      @user = user
    end

    def process
      WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        ApplicationController.new.render_to_string(
          template: 'services/main.pdf.erb',
          locals: { user: user}
        )
        margin: { top: 10, bottom: 20 }
      )
    end

    private

    attr_reader :user
  end
end

main.pdf.erb
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<div class="letter">
  <div class='header'>
    <div class='header-right'>
      <b>Letter</b>
    </div>
    <div class='logo'>
      <% if @user.client %>
        <%= image_tag Setting.take.logo.url, size: "100x50" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= image_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64('mailer/logo.png') %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

The image is present in Settings table but doest show in pdf.erb file. I thing this issue is how to use image_tag to display image in service. Not 100% sure . Please help me resolve it
Setting.take.logo.url is
/uploads/setting/logo/1/America_1.png


Just a shot in the dark here but it probably has something to do with the fact that the src "url" is a relative path rather than a full URL

@engineersmnky that is not the case because I using Setting.take.logo.url like in mailer/send_user.html.erb file and there it works fine. It has something to do with how wickedpdf is used in service

@engineersmnky this image is displayed <%= image_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64('mailer/logo.png') %> when user is not a client

According to the docs you may need to use wicked_pdf_image_tag because as I mentioned it needs an absolute reference (a true URL).

@engineersmnky this is the location of the file where it is stored on my local. The code I am trying above is on my local.
/Users/xyz/Documents/project/onboarding_app/public/uploads/setting/logo/1/America_1.png

@engineersmnky
Yes I did try
<%= image_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64(Setting.take.logo.url), size: "100x50" %>
returns error
Could not find asset 'uploads/setting/logo/1/America_1.png'

@engineersmnky even tried <%= wicked_pdf_image_tag Setting.take.logo.url %> still no luck image doesnt show on generated pdf

Okay last attempt I can think of. Please try asset_url(Setting.take.logo.url, skip_pipeline: true) you may have to pass the host option as well if config.action_controller.asset_host is not set or set incorrectly. e.g. host: 'http://mywebsite.com'

 This worked for me

@engineersmnky you can post the answer and I ll check mark it. Thankyou for all your help

You solved it for yourself all I did was talk about it. Feel free to post your own answer. I'll even upvote it. Although URI.join(Setting.default.host,Setting.take.logo.url) would be more idiomatic and if you need this more frequently I would suggest making it a method in Settings e.g. def full_url(asset_path)= URI.join(Setting.default.host,asset_path)

For locally stored assets you can actually use a file path instead of a URL. It needs to be an absolute path instead of a relative one.

<img src="<%= Settings.default.host + Setting.take.logo.url %>">
This worked for me
